# Highcharts hover xAxis Labels Unique Value

Tags: regex, angular, typescript, highcharts, hover

New to highcharts issues.

Have a function that parses labels for the xAxis for my scatter chart. Works fine, but the values are too long and get truncated. These need shown on hover while the value shown on xAxis label should be the last word in the string that is surrounded by brackets. Example and code is below. Having a time trying to find anything about changing the hover result for the xAxis in a Highchart.

**Original string:** root.D_seasonality.D_poly[poly0]

**After parseLabels function. Visible chart label:** "poly0".

**Intended Hover:** "seasonality_trend_poly0" (Current chart label).

Have tried to format or insert a function into HighchartOptions/xAxis, but no luck.

**Typescript:**

```
    parseLabels(uniqueFeatures) {
    this.labels = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < uniqueFeatures.length; i++) {

      let trimmedFeature = '';

      let curFeature = uniqueFeatures[i];
      let start = curFeature.search('>') + 4;
      curFeature = curFeature.substr(start, curFeature.length);

      let end = curFeature.search('<');
      if (end === -1) {
        end = curFeature.search('\\[');
      }

      let key = curFeature.substr(0, end);

      trimmedFeature = trimmedFeature + key;
      curFeature = curFeature.substr(end + 1, curFeature.length);

      start = 0;
      end = curFeature.search('>');

      if (end === -1) {
        if (trimmedFeature.length > 1) {
          this.labels.push(trimmedFeature);
        }
      } else {

        key = curFeature.substr(start, end);

        trimmedFeature = trimmedFeature + '_' + key;
        curFeature = curFeature.substr(end + 1, curFeature.length);

        start = curFeature.search('\\[') + 1;

        if (start !== -1) {

        } else {
          if (trimmedFeature.length > 4) {
            this.labels.push(trimmedFeature);
          }
        }

        end = curFeature.search('\\]');
        key = curFeature.substr(start, (end - start));

        trimmedFeature = trimmedFeature + '_' + key;

        if (trimmedFeature.length > 4) {
          this.labels.push(trimmedFeature);
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you want `root.D_seasonality.D_poly[poly0]` to become `seasonality_trend_poly0`? If so, where does `trend` come from?

Comment: Sorry, the original string is actually "root<trace>.D_seasonality<trend>.D_poly[poly0]" It's removing the <> portion.

Comment: Does [`<[^>]*>[^_]*|([^_]+)\[\1([^]]*)]$`](https://regex101.com/r/gohtdk/2) work for you?

Comment: Would actually need to be "seasonality_trend_poly0". Then another to only capture the portion in the brackets at the end, "poly0". Longer string should be the hover and shorter one the actualy xAxis label.

Comment: Can you add some more samples with their expected outputs to your question? It helps us ensure we provide a working regex for all your given samples (just in case there are some special cases)

Comment: Sure. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: **Original string:** "root<trace>.D_seasonality<trend>.D_poly[poly0]"
   "root<trace>.D_seasonality<trend>.D_poly[poly2]"
   "root<trace>.D_seasonality<seasonality>.F_spectral_entropy[spectral_entropy]"

**Current chart label(after parseLabels function. want this as hover):** "seasonality_trend_poly0"
              "seasonality_trend_poly2"
              "seasonality_seasonality_spectral_entropy"

**Intended chart label(last phrase in brackets):** "poly0"
        "poly2"
        "spectral_entropy"

Comment: Are you trying to perform a regex replace on the strings or a match? I think it's probably easier to do a regex replace for the first set of outputs but a match for the second. It's easier to run two regex patterns for this than one (and probably more manageable) but it's up to you.

Comment: yes I'm planning doing two. One for the hover result and one for the actual chart label. Just did an ugly function and worked to grab everything in brackets for the xAxis label, but not sure how to have the hover different from that. Sorry, regex is still new to me...

Comment: I've posted an answer. I decided to combine them since I found it to be a much easier approach than using two regex patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should do what you're looking for. Run the snippet below to see it in use.

```
^[^_]*_([^<]*)<([^>]*)>[^[]*\[([^\]]*)]
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^_]*` Match anything except `_` any number of times
- `_` Match this literally
- `([^<]*)` Capture any character except `<` any number of times into capture group **1**
- `<` Match this literally
- `([^>]*)` Capture any character except `>` any number of times into capture group **2**
- `>` Match this literally
- `[^[]*` Match any character except `[` any number of times
- `\[` Match `[` literally
- `([^\]]*)` Capture any character except `]` any number of times into capture group **3**
- `]` Match this literally

```js
const r = /^[^_]*_([^<]*)<([^>]*)>[^[]*\[([^\]]*)]/
const a = [
  'root<trace>.D_seasonality<trend>.D_poly[poly0]',
  'root<trace>.D_seasonality<trend>.D_poly[poly2]',
  'root<trace>.D_seasonality<seasonality>.F_spectral_entropy[spectral_entropy]'
]

a.forEach(function(s) {
  m = r.exec(s)
  console.log(`Hover: ${m[1]}_${m[2]}_${m[3]}`)
  console.log(`Label: ${m[3]}`)
})
```

Comment: Thanks that helps immensely! Now I just need to figure out how to customize the hover on mouseover of xaxis value specifically from the label.  Creating a hover or onmouseover in highcharts is eluding me completely . Thanks for taking a look. This got me through the first steps!